# WebView on orientation changed

Tags: android, iframe, webview, android-orientation

I have an `iframe` that looks like this:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="-----source----" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and handle orientation by my self in `onConfigurationChanged`. as layout changed the height and width changes as well. the issue is that after rotation iframe *(from time to time)* not fills the whole `webview`.

`webview` settings:

```
mWebView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout
                .LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
mWebView.setScrollContainer(false);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
mWebView.setInitialScale(1);
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

so it looks like that:

[image]

how to force it to fill all webview content?

p.s: when i load `hppts` pages it works ok, the issue with `iframes` only.

Comment: The problem is the percentage that you use. Webview doesn't work very good with only percentage. You need at least one is it width or height in px.

Comment: @Steven you are right, thank you. could you make the post, i'll mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android webview you have a problem with percentage. 
What I mean is if you declare by example a `div/iframe` like this:

```
iframe{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

this won't work because if you use both % on `width` and on `height`.
You will get a small screen like in the photo in the question.

So how to solve this problem? You need at least one declared in px.
You need to declare `width` or `height` in px.

So a few examples:

```
iframe{
        height: 1500px;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

or

```
iframe{
        height: 100%;
        width: 1500px;
    }
```